# Log onto Stack Exchange websites without a Mouse

Tags: keyboard

How can one log onto (for example) superuser using one's gmail account without using a mouse on a web browser like google chrome?

My general techniques for browsing the internet and open links without a mouse have been to search for texts, press esc, and then return. However, I have not been able to discover a way to log into a stackexchange website using gmail without a mouse. On the log in page, the "Log in using google" can not be open either using a search or even repeated tabs. From this page, is there some way to effectively "click" on the picture without using the mouse.

Also I am aware that I could probably just save the web address of the google login page for superuser, but my real question is not so much how to log into this particular website, but how in general I can handle those type of links without a mouse.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just use the `Stackexchange Windows Store` application.  As for any website most of time this sort of navigation is done by the author of the website and has to be programmed to be possible.

Comment: There are tools (for example this one under Windows: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/touchcursor-control-cursor-with-keyboard/) that enable you to control the mouse with the keyboard. But maybe this doesn't fit the intention of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the Chrome (or FF) extension **Vimium** (or similar). It allows very intuitive controls for your browser (using Vim commands). Don't know how to us Vim?? Does not matter in my opinion, you could still benefit greatly from this extension, it will just require a glance at some basic commands. Such as:

"k" up -- "j" down
"/" + "search string" to search
"n" for next result, "N" for previous result
And the most important:
**"f" + "# for link, or identifying strings" to jump to hyperlink.**

In Vimium `f` will display an index number for each link/button on the page. And then typing that number will click on the link.

(if you are stuck in a text input box, be sure to hit ESC and then you can use a command)